# Using jquery autocomplete Django form

Tags: django, django-forms, jquery-autocomplete

I am using `jquery autocomplete` with my `generic views` on Django. I am getting the list via AJAX, but there is one problem. When the user get the category he wants, he will select that value. Thus, if I append the `value` on that field `$("#id_category").val(ui.item.value);` it will show the pk on that field instead of value, so if I append `$("#id_category").val(ui.item.label);` django will complain it should be the instance. Django is completely right. How to make this work?

**Edit:**
I have made `id_category` hidden field and added `category_display` to append the text value. It is working. But while editing the category_display would be empty. Again I am using generic view. How to solve this one on the edit?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I suggest you to think about question: 'What will happen if user enters not valid category name(category with this name doesn`t exist)?'

if you need to accept entered value and add new category, you have to make clean_category method in form:

```
def clean_category(self):
    name = self.data['category']
    return Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
```

and display ui.item.label for user

if new category isn`t acceptable you can raise error in clean_category method or use something like select2(http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) for your field. I choose second variant.